# How to stop munin from calculating the values in millis?

Tags: munin

I wrote my own munin-plugin and I'm confused, how munin represents values between 0 and 1.
[image: plugin values]
The 2nd line of values uses an notation with 'n'. What does it mean and how can I avoid it? I just want a common floating point value like `0.33`!
What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the plugin configuration:

```
graph_title Title
graph_args --base 1000 -l 0
graph_vlabel label
graph_category backup
```

Every hint is welcome.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I finally found it: https://serverfault.com/questions/123761/what-does-the-m-unit-in-munin-mean

'm' stands for  milli!

I am a bit confused, why munin is using it in this context!

Is there any possibility to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some configuration items that may be of interest. See [Munin Plugin Reference](https://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/reference/plugin.html).

You may change the resolution in numeric resolution in the table data with the below.   Use C/C++ formatting, and spacing may be an issue in end result.

```
graph_printf %5.2le     # default is %6.2lf
                        # appears l (for long) is needed
```

For certain graph types you can also alter the display period for the munin graph.  Munin graphs the average data between last two (nominally 5 minute spaced) measurements - with default of `per/sec` units on the result.  This is based on the `var.type` attribute which defaults to `GAUGE`.  If your for example data is reporting accumulated counts you can use:

```
type DERIVE         # data displayed is change from last 
                    #   reading 
type COUNTER        # accumulating counter with reset on rollover
```

for each of these you can change the vertical axis to use `per/minute` or `per/hour`  with:

```
graph_period minute # if type DERIVE or COUNTER  
                    # display avg/period vs default of avg/sec
```

Note that the table shows the derived data for the graph_period.
See [RRDCreate == rrdtool create](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html) for implementation particulars- munin used rrd underneath.